# C# LINQ XML filtering by attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML:

```
<PlayerSetup>
    <CardDeck name="deckOfCards"/>
    <Card name="one"/>
    <Card name="two"/>
    <Card name="three"/>
    <Card name="four"/>
    <Token name="four"/>
</PlayerSetup>
```

I need to retrieve only the elements which attributes name="four", I have the following code:

```
var query = from d in xdoc.Descendants("PlayerSetup")
             where (string)d.Attribute("name").Value == "four"
             select d;
```

Which of course, is not working, returns no elements. Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: You mean you want 1) the `PlayerSetup` elements with a descendant element with attribute name="four"; or 2) the descendant elements of `PlayerSetup` with attribute name="four"?

Comment: `name` is an attribute of `Card` not `PlayerSetup`

Comment: Yes, name is attribute of Card, not PlayerSetup, @Eser thanks for your answer, I was actually close to it but I didn't know that I could use multiple Descendants() to keep "digging" into the xml tree.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the descendant elements under the `"PlayerSetup"` elements with name="four", you can do:

```
        var query = from d in xdoc.Descendants("PlayerSetup").Descendants()
                    where (string)d.Attribute("name") == "four"
                    select d;
```

If you want the `"PlayerSetup"` elements who have at least one descendant element with name="four", you can do:

```
        var query = from d in xdoc.Descendants("PlayerSetup")
                    where d.Descendants().Any(c => (string)c.Attribute("name") == "four")
                    select d;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are wanting to look at the `Descendants` *of* `PlayerSetup`, so grab those:

```
var query = from d in xdoc.Descendants("PlayerSetup").Descendants()
            where d.Attribute("name")?.Value == "four"
            select d;

//query.Count == 2
```

this solution uses C#6 syntax

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is already known for a long time.

You can find it here:
[LINQ to XML query attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591096/linq-to-xml-query-attributes)

or here:
[How to get attribute names of element in xml by LINQ in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458115/how-to-get-attribute-names-of-element-in-xml-by-linq-in-c-sharp)

:)

Comment: I already saw the first link and didn't work for my example, but thanks